# How to recover Gradle files from APK file?

Tags: java, android, apk, android-gradle-plugin

I've succeeded in recovering the Java files and XML files from an APK file using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euaGbxxdBKc) tutorial but I cannot find the Gradle scripts( build.gradle, settings gradle, local.properties, etc.)

I've created a new project and I had imported the Java and XML files but the project doesn't work, I guess because of the Gradle.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your own folders in the studio and try copying the code into the studio....that should work...and about gradle files? android studio will build it with gradle...as much as i know studio uses gradle build system to build app

Comment: What about dependencies and modules?

Answer (score 37):

The gradle file is not compiled into the APK, it is only for the actual android studio project for fetching dependencies and app configuration. There is no way to get a gradle file from an APK

Comment: Further, not only is there no way to get the originals from the apk, there's no guarantee that even if available the original build configuration files would be a match for the recompiled (**not** "recovered") java and xml files.  Likely coming up with a workable build will be the simplest of all, perhaps by importing these files into an appropriate IDE.

Comment: I had created a new project and I had imported the java and xml files but it doesn't work. The new project was a workable build before adding those files

Comment: apk decompilation will never give you a 1 to 1 copy of what it was before hand. it likely is messed up somewhere, and is probably easier to start over and slowly start porting over features from the old app by hand

Comment: That's discouraging.. Because I don't have the old app, only the apk file.

Answer (score 2):

you can’t . when you compile apk it will merge all the file into single file . An APK file contains all of that program's code (such as .dex files), resources, assets, certificates, and manifest file.

So When You decompile it . you can not file gradle file .

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read in terms of [Apktool vs JADX: Pros and Cons](https://www.slant.co/versus/10232/30245/%7Eapktool_vs_jadx), **JADX** apparently decompiles APK files to Java Code and also has the option to allow you to save said Decompiled APK as a Gradle project, it has CLI version as well as a GUI version.

however I noticed that one of the Cons of JADX comes from when the APK that JADX is being used on, contains some non-ASCII characters, causing the Decompiling process to fail.

Maybe this could work for you, not sure if it will give you exactly what you want in terms of original Gradle files but it might be a step in the right direction.

You can find more information about JADX, from the creators [Jadx GitHub repository](https://github.com/skylot/jadx), Note that it doesn't work on every APK you use it on.

Hope this helps.