# Storing a string in android as securely as possible even when app is disassembled

Tags: android, encryption

I have a certain string that is used by my android app and has to be stored in the app. How do I prevent the string from being seen or make it as hard as possible in case anyone gets to disassemble my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your secure string like API key etc. in gradle file

**Build.gradle** App level

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"API_KEY_SERVER\""
    }
}
```

Separate configuration for Debug and Release

```
android {
  buildTypes {
        release {
           buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"RELEASE_API_KEY\""
         }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"DEBUG_API_KEY\""
         }
     }
 }
```

To access this string in code using

BuildConfig.API_KEY Make sure to import proper BuildConfig.

Comment: Okay,but what makes this secure? Can't it be disassembled?

Comment: Check it out. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-the-gradle-file-after-decompiling-an-APK

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808504/how-to-recover-gradle-files-from-apk-file

Comment: Or you can use some encryption/decryption for your strings